# Definition of Rudin-Keisler ordering

Tags: set-theory, filters

According to Wikipedia, we can  define an [order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ordering_on_ultrafilters) on ultrafilters. However, it seems the  definition  has an error. It says that:

> If $U$ and $V$ are ultrafilters on $S$ and $T$, respectively, then $V \subseteq U$ iff there exists a function $f:\, S \rightarrow T$ such that 
>   (letting $g$ be the inverse of $f$), we have 
>   $C \in V$ iff $g[C] \in U$.

But we can get the inverse of a function only if it is a bijection, so I do not understand this definition. For example, since $V$ is ultrafilter on $T$, then $T$ is an element of $V$, so $g[T]$ should be an element of $U$ but, since $f$ is not bijective, then $g[T]$ is non-sense.

I need your help.

Comment: Rather than $V\subseteq U$, you want to write $V\le_{RK} U$, "$V$ is Rudin-Keisler reducible to $U$". The *reduction* is the function $f$. Here, $g[C]=f^{-1}[C]=\{t\in S\mid f(t)\in C\}$ is the *preimage* of $C$ under $f$. Note that this is well-defined, and makes sense, regardless of whether $f$ is injective. This is a subset of $S$, so it may or may not be in $U$, and that $f$ is a reduction says that a subset of $T$ is in $V$ iff its preimage is in $U$. Note in particular that $g[T]=\{a\in S\mid f(a)\in T\}=S$ is certainly in $U$.

Answer (score 1):

As Andres comments, this is not the inverse function, but rather the **preimage**. Recall that $f$ is a function then it is also a relation, then $f^{-1}$ is just the inverse relation. When we write $f^{-1}[A]$ (and in many places using parentheses rather than brackets) we write the set $\{x\mid f(x)\in A\}$. This is the dual notion of the **direct image**, $f[B]=\{f(b)\mid b\in B\}$.

If $f\colon X\to Y$ then both the direct image and preimage are functions between the power sets of $X$ and $Y$. That is, the preimage, which we shall denote by $\hat f(A)=f^{-1}(A)$ is a function from $\mathcal P(Y)$ to $\mathcal P(X)$. The direct image is in the other way.

Now we say that $V\leq_{RK} U$ if there is a function $f$ such that $V=\hat f^{-1}[U]$. That is to say, $V$ is exactly the preimages of the sets which are in $U$.